# Translating forms of Yirah as Fear or Seeing

Tags: hebrew, psalms

I have heard numerous rabbis connect verses about the fear of God to seeing God.

This always hinges on the fact that some of the conjugations of [yirah](https://biblehub.com/hebrew/strongs_3374.htm) (fear) look the same as some of the conjugations of [raah](https://biblehub.com/hebrew/7200.htm) (to see). For example, this weekend I've heard the first phrase in  [ps 111:10](https://biblehub.com/interlinear/psalms/111-10.htm) translated as *to see God is the beginning of wisdom* (רֵ֘אשִׁ֤ית חָכְמָ֨ה׀ יִרְאַ֬ת יְהוָ֗ה, Psalm 111:10, MT) Logos Bible Software has יִרְאַ֬ת a feminine singular construct noun meaning fear of.  The verb רָאָה meaining see begins with a yod in the imperfect (Impf. 3 ms. יִרְאֶה  +, juss. יֵרֵא).  How can one get a taw at the end of the conjugation of רָאָה?

My Hebrew is not good enough to gauge how valid this translation is in this verse or in the [many other verses](https://bible.knowing-jesus.com/topics/Fear-Of-God,-Results-Of) that have variations of the phrase.

I think evaluating this may have interesting consequences. Proverbs and Ecclesiastes contain many verses about being aware of things and the prophetic books put a huge emphasis on the apparent/inapparent or seen/unseen. If translating some of these verses as being about seeing rather than fear is supportable it could lead to an interesting way of reading large portions of scripture.

Comment: I have fixed the broken link to _raah_ for you. I didn't notice any identical inflections between _raah_ and _yirah_. Perhaps you could point these out for us. I would suggest you confine this question to a specific text (ideally one in which the inflection could be read as either word) otherwise the question could be voted for closure on the basis of being a 'topic' (which is, here, off-topic) rather than an inquiry about a text.

Comment: Thanks, this problem is beyond my skill in hebrew. Here is a form of to see that that looks like fear, however, I am not sure if the grammer in ps 110:1 or the other verses would allow us to read yrah that way. https://www.biblehub.com/hebrew/yireh_7200.htm

Comment: also i am not sure if its the only form of one word that looks like the other

Comment: If your question gets closed, you could ask it on Mi Yodeya https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions

Comment: For this to word you would have to change יִרְאַ֬ת form a noun to an verb in the imperfect tense.

Comment: I haven't been able to get an exact match with the imperfect tense.

Comment: I'll wait a little while now that the sabbath is over to see if more respond then post a question on  Mi Yodeya (judaism.stackexchange.com/questions) that asks about the Hebrew involved, not necessarily specific to this verse.

Comment: I've posted the question here: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/118123/are-there-any-cases-in-the-tanakh-a-word-could-have-either-the-root-%d7%99%d6%b8%d7%a8%d6%b5%d7%90-fear

Comment: Thanks, for now the responses to your post are a litte above my head, but I'll go through them with a freind and that should hopefully clarify everything

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Abijah, Do you understand enough from https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/118123/are-there-any-cases-in-the-tanakh-where-the-form-of-the-word-could-ambiguously-h? to answer your question?  No one found a Hebrew word in the Tanakh (MT) that could ambiguously be a form of both yirah and raah.  There were some textual variations that were ether one or the other.  Basically you can trust the English translations.

Comment: Excellent answer and excellently researched on the other site. First class. (Up-voted +1.)

Answer (score 2):

Is the verb "[יראת](https://www.pealim.com/dict/847-liro/)" [he/she Feared]; past 2nd-person singular, Synonymous with Seeing?

- Wisdom (חָכְמָ֨ה) can be aquired without Eyes.
- **Fear of YHVH (יִרְאַ֬ת יְהוָ֗ה)** is not linked with Seeing, but **Understanding (בִּינָֽה)**.

---

**Tehillim / Psalms 111:10** [MT]

> "Beginning (רֵ֘אשִׁ֤ית) [of] Wisdom (חָכְמָ֨ה) [is] Fear (יִרְאַ֬ת) [of] Yehovah (יְהוָ֗ה)".

**Mishlei / Proverbs 1:7** [MT]

> "Fear" (יִרְאַ֣ת) [of] Yehovah (יְ֭הוָה) [is] Beginning (רֵאשִׁ֣ית) [of] Knowledge (דָּ֑עַת)".

**Mishlei / Proverbs 9:10** [MT]

> "Beginning (תְּחִלַּ֣ת) [of] Wisdom (חָ֭כְמָה) [is] Fear (יִרְאַ֣ת) [of] Yehovah (יְהוָ֑ה), And-Knowledge (וְדַ֖עַת) of Holies (קְדֹשִׁ֣ים) [is] Understanding (בִּינָֽה).

---

In conclusion the prophet Yeshayahu explains Seeing is not Understanding in Isaiah 6:9.

**Yeshayahu / Isaiah 6:9** [MT]

> "And He said, Go and say to this people, Indeed you hear, but you do not understand; indeed you see, but you do not know." (וַיֹּ֕אמֶר לֵ֥ךְ וְאָֽמַרְתָּ֖ לָעָ֣ם הַזֶּ֑ה שִׁמְע֚וּ שָׁמ֙וֹעַ֙ וְאַל־תָּבִ֔ינוּ וּרְא֥וּ רָא֖וֹ וְאַל־תֵּדָֽעוּ)

Comment: Thanks, that looks really good, but could you unpack it a bit more? For example is the translation of ps 111:10 something you would reject on gramtical grounds? also how would you justify that?